# Can you pass weights for a text search to create_index in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an automated process that creates a text index on various fields in a Mongo instance (current Mongo 2.6 / PyMongo 2.72).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, TEXT
db = MongoClient()
collection = db.collection

collection.create_index([("foo",TEXT), ("bar",TEXT), ("baz",TEXT)])
```

I want to weight the collection according to the [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/). In the Mongo shell, this would be:

```
db.collection.create_index( { foo: text, bar: text, baz: text}, {weights: {foo: 10, bar: 5, baz 1}})
```

However, since I'm doing this in Python and not the Mongo shell. Does PyMongo support this?

Answer (score 9):

In Python (PyMongo 2.4.2 and newer), the index declaration looks like:

```
collection.create_index(
    [
        ('foo', TEXT),
        ('bar', TEXT),
        ('baz', TEXT)
    ],
    weights={
        'foo': 10,
        'bar': 5,
        'baz': 1
    }
)
```

Comment: excellent, thanks much. I should have just tried the keyword like that. Appreciate it.

Comment: This still doesn't appear to be in the official documentation, hopefully that will be fixed.